# How to retry a kafka message when there is an error - spring cloud stream

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, stream

I'm pretty new to Kafka. I'm using spring cloud stream Kafka to produce and consume

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
 public void process(Order order) {

       try {
      // have my message processing 

    }
    catch( exception e ) {
       //retry here that record..
     }
    }
 }
```

Just want to know how can I implement a retry ? Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Retrying and processing the same message with same logic will give you same error? What exactly you want to do in a retry ?

Answer (score 0):

Hy

There are multiple ways to handle "retries" and it depends on the kind of events you encounter.

For basic issues kafka framework will retry for you to recover from an error condition, for example in case of a short network downtime the consumer and producer api implement auto retry.

In particular kafka support "built-in producer/consumer retries" to correctly handle a large variety of errors without loss of messages, but as a developer, you must still be able to handle other types of errors with the try-catch block you mention.

Error in kafka can be divided in the following categories:

- (producer & consumer side) Nonretriable broker errors such as errors regarding message size, authorization errors, etc -> you must handle them in "design phase" of your app.
- (producer side) Errors that occur before the message was sent to the broker—for example, serialization errors --> you must handle them in the runtime app execution
- (producer & consumer sideErrors that occur when the producer exhausted all retry attempts or when the
  available memory used by the producer is filled to the limit due to using all of it to store messages while retrying -> you should handle these errors.

Another point of attention regarding "how to retry" is how to handle correctly the order of commits in case of auto-commit option is set to false.

A common and simple pattern to get commit order right is to use a monotonically increasing sequence number. Increase the sequence number every time you commit and add the sequence number at the time of the commit to the commit function.

When you’re getting ready to send a retry, check if the
commit sequence number the callback got is equal to the instance
variable; if it is, there was no newer commit and it is safe to retry. If
the instance sequence number is higher, don’t retry because a
newer commit was already sent.

Comment: You are welcome, if the answer has satisfied your question please mark as "accepted" the answer.